# Is zero vector potential for Helmholtz decomposition of curl and divergence free vector fields necessary?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Helmholtz's theorem tells us that a sufficiently smooth vector field $\mathbf{A}$ can be decomposed into curl and gradient free parts as the gradient of a scalar potential plus the curl of a vector potential  $$ \mathbf{A} = \nabla \phi + \nabla \times \mathbf{B}$$ Given the constraint that the vector field must be divergence and curl free  $$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$$  $$ \nabla \times \mathbf{A} = 0$$ this leads to $$\nabla^2 \phi = 0 $$ $$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{B}) = 0$$  In application, such as potential flow theroy, it is often taken as a given that $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{A} = \nabla \phi$.  I can see no reason that this is absolutely required.  Other than simplification, is there a justification for $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{0}$?  For potential flow theory the choice leads to useful solutions, but is it ignoring a subset of possible solutions?

**Edit**: There are certainly solutions that have non-zero $\mathbf{B}$ that satify the divergence free and curl free constraints.  For instance $$\phi = 0$$ $$\mathbf{B}=\alpha y \hat{i}+\beta x\hat{j}$$  which gives $$\mathbf{A} = \beta-\alpha$$ for constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Any constant vector field satisfies the divergence and curl free constraint.  My intuition is that while $\mathbf{B}=0$ is not necessary, it simply does not add any new unique solution that can't be found by simply satisfying the constraints with $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

In electromagentism, the definition of $\mathbf{B}$ through $\mathbf{A}$ is: $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times \mathbf{A}$, which gives a-priori, the Helmoltz decomposition of $\mathbf{B}$. This is because $\mathbf{A}$ is the [vector magnetic potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential) and $\mathbf{B}$ is the associated magnetic field. So $\mathbf{B}=0$ if $\nabla\times \mathbf{A}=0$.

There is no reason otherwise to take $\mathbf{B}=0$. For example, $\mathbf{B}$ can equal a constant and trivially satisfy all of the conditions above.

Comment: yes, but can you have $\phi = 0$ and satisfy the curl and divergence free constraint on $\mathbf{A}$ with a $\mathbf{B}$ that leads to a non-constant $\mathbf{A}$.  That is basically what I'm asking.